# How do I pipe a property of a PowerShell cmdlet output into an input of a different cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, pipeline

The specific use case is:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection -State Listen -LocalPort 6005 |
    Get-Process -PID ???
```

Where `???` is the `OwningProcess` property of the output from the first cmdlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-Id` parameter accepts pipeline input by property name, so you'd have to add another property with the proper name containing the PID. While possible, I'd usually just use the direct route:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection | ForEach-Object { Get-Process -Id $_.OwningProcess }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple options here that I can see. First, and simplest, you can pipe it to a `ForEach-Object` loop, and run `Get-Process` in that:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection -State Listen -LocalPort 6005 | 
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-Process -PID $_.OwningProcess
    }
```

Alternatively if you run `Get-Help Get-Process -PArameter Id` you can see that the Id parameter accepts values from the pipeline by property name, so you could create that property, and just pipe directly to `Get-Process`:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection -State Listen -LocalPort 6005 | 
    Select @{l='Id';e={$_.OwningProcess}} |
    Get-Process
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple of ways to do this. When the variables cannot be matched by property you can either use a `ForEach-Object` loop like in [Joey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43528988/3829407) or if you wanted to do something crazy you can tailor the pipeline object to fits the needs.

```
Get-NetTCPConnection -State Listen -LocalPort 6005 |
    Select-Object @{Name="PID";E={$_.OwningProcess}} | 
    Get-Process
```

Since `Get-Process` is looking to match the pipeline variable property PID we just use a calculated property to give it what it wants.

Using `ForEach-Object` in this case is much simpler. Just wanted you to know there was another way.